# Rails pass :id with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Using the rails `button_to` helper I'm trying to run the `update` method in a controller.  I need to set the ID of the object being updated manually.  The code I have I think should be right, but rails keeps trying to put the ID as part of a route.

in the view:

```
button_to ">", :controller=>'people', :action=>'update', 'person'=>{:team=>team_leader.team}, :id=>currently_viewing_person
```

in the controller:

```
  def update
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    #...rest of method
  end
```

The controller update method is never executed.  The error on the web browser is:

```
Unknown action

No action responded to 3. Actions: create, index, new, search, show, and update
```

'3' was the value of `currently_viewing_person`

What's the correct way to pass `:id` so update can extract from `params[:id]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`button_to` uses POST by default. For update you need a PUT, so pass in the method along with the other parameters:

```
button_to ">", 
  { :controller=>'people', :action=>'update',
    'person'=>{:team=>team_leader.team}, 
    :id=>currently_viewing_person }, 
  :method => :put
```

Note that the method has to be passed in as a separate hash

Answer (score 0):

Here's to reading the documentation again, and understanding that in a REST architecture, update is sent via `PUT`, not `POST`.  The correct view code is:

```
button_to ">", {:controller=>'people', :action=>'update', 'person'=>{:team=>team_leader.team}, :id=>currently_viewing_person}, :method => :put
```

Oddly, if I view source on this page the form created by button_to shows `POST` being used:

```
<form method="post" ...
```

But the rails log confirms that PUT was indeed used:

```
Processing PeopleController#update (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-07-15 00:10:09) [PUT]
```

Comment: Heh -- you beat me by seconds :)  The reason for the `<form method="post"` is that browsers don't do PUTs (or DELETEs), so they emulate them with a POST. You'll see a "_method" => "put" or somesuch posted in the form data.